# How to populate a list of generic lists in Java?

Tags: java

Observe the following code:

```
private List<List<Place>> m_grid = constructGrid(10000);

private static List<List<Place>> constructGrid(int size) {
  List<List<Place>> res = new ArrayList<List<Place>>(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    res.add(null);
  }
  return res;
}
```

It is dull. Is there a prettier way to do the same thing? A one liner using some kind of a standard library?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The list must be mutable. Hence, `Collections.nCopies` does not fit the bill.

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean. Do you want to preinitialize the outer list with just 10,000 null elements?

Comment: Dull isn't the worst of it.  Magic numbers are never a good idea.  And all those list references are already null.  You didn't do anything useful here.  I'd prefer initializing them to empty lists.  Why preinitialize?  Just add as needed.

Comment: @duffymo: after this code, the size of the list is 10000 instead of 0 without this code. Not saying executing this code is a good idea, but it's not the same thing as not executing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really get why you need `10000` nulls in your list, but if you want to do this, you can do:

```
List<List<Place>> tmp = Collections.nCopies(10000, null); // immutable
List<List<Place>> res = new ArrayList<List<Place>>(tmp);  // mutable
```

Comment: I looked it up just for this `:D`

Comment: @mark: you could just create a new list (of course some heap pollution): `new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(10000, null));`

Comment: @beerbajay - can you update the answer, so that I can credit you?

Comment: @home Fortunately, the tmp list doesn't actually contain 10,000 copies of null, it just pretends to (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,+T))